# Creating non-conflicting jQuery functions using an array

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the below jQuery code that I copied from another site and need to modify it to work with my setup.

The code currently (I think anyways) won't work if I copy and paste the function and just change the html id element identifier.

How can I duplicate this code chunk and make it unique so they don't conflict with each other?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#hccfavicon').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#hccfavicon').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
```

You see #hccfavicon.  That's the item I'd be swapping for the various instances where I need to use this jQuery function.

Comment: Do you know what the code does? Don't copy and paste blindly... The code doesn't look that complicated so you could probably have just written it yourself...

Comment: Yeah I know what it does and it works fine where I put it after a small modification, I just don't know jQuery, hence my question.

Comment: I modified my code like this > http://pastebin.com/G1G3Qtpp but now when I select an image, it updates the second instance and the first instance doesn't change...

Comment: Because you're modifying and accessing variables that are NOT a part of this scope ( `formfield`, `imgurl`, `window.send_to_editor` ) its going to be difficult to make this code reusable.  Mainly the `send_to_editor` function...